# Как передать методом post src изображения?

Tags: php, post

Как передать **src** изображения методом post? Зарание спасибо)

```
<form action='reload.php' method = 'post'>
  <img class='image' src='img/1.png'>
  <input type='submit' name='button'>
</form>

$name = $_POST['image_src'];
```

Comment: Вы ходите передать на сервер файл или строку 'img/1.png'?

Comment: ArchDemon Строку 'img/1.png', чтобы ее потом можно было в переменную задать

Comment: `<input type='hidden' name='image_src' value="img/1.png">`

Answer (score -1):

либо нужно с помощью `js`вбить `src` изображения в `input`, либо воспользоваться формой `upload` файла и потом вытянуть src выбранного изображения на стороне сервера

```
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
   <p><input type="file" name="f">
   <input type="submit" value="Отправить"></p>
  </form>
```

Comment: А зачем вы элементы формы в тэг <p> обернули? С вами все хорошо? И зачем тут отправка файла?

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов тег ничему не мешает...хотите не оборачивайте. Я написал 2 варианта как можно вытянуть имя, т к вопрос изначально не понятен со стороны логики.

Comment: Ну, кажется, человек, который задавал вопрос написал то, что ему нужно сделать? Разве нет? "Как передать src изображения методом post." - как в этом вопросе можно увидеть что либо связонное с передачей файлов?  Что значит не хотите оборачивайте? Вы же для чего то это написали? Тэг <p> определяет текстовый абзац. Для чего вы поместили в него элементы формы? Вам он может и не мешает, но верстку делает невалидной.